# SpannableStringBuffer limited to 9,999 characters?

Tags: android, lg, spannablestring, spannable

My app reads in large amounts of data from text files assets and displays them on-screen in a TextView.  (The largest is ~450k.)  I read the file in, line-by-line into a [SpannableStringBuffer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder.html) (since there is some metadata I remove, such as section names).  This approach has worked without complaints in the two years that I've had the app on the market (over 7k active device installs), so I know that the code is reasonably correct.

However, I got a recent report from a user on a [LG Lucid](http://www.lg.com/us/support-mobile/lg-VS840) (LGE VS840 4G, Android 2.3.6) that the text is truncated.  From log entries, my app only got 9,999 characters in the buffer.  Is this a known issue with a [SpannableStringBuffer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder.html)?  Are there other recommended ways to build a large [Spannable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spannable.html%20Spannable) buffer?  Any suggested workarounds?

Other than keeping a separate expected length that I update each time I append to the [SpannableStringBuilder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder.html), I don't even have a good way to detect the error, since the append interface returns the object, not an error!

My code that reads in the data is:

```
    currentOffset = 0;
    try {
        InputStream is = getAssets().open(filename);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        ssb.clear();
        jumpOffsets.clear();
        ArrayList<String> sectionNamesList = new ArrayList<String>();
        sectionOffsets.clear();
        int offset = 0;
        while (br.ready()) {
            String s = br.readLine();
            if (s.length() == 0) {
                ssb.append("\n");
                ++offset;
            } else if (s.charAt(0) == '\013') {
                jumpOffsets.add(offset);
                String name = s.substring(1);
                if (name.length() > 0) {
                    sectionNamesList.add(name);
                    sectionOffsets.add(offset);
                    if (showSectionNames) {
                        ssb.append(name);
                        ssb.append("\n");
                        offset += name.length() + 1;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (!showNikud) {
                    // Remove nikud based on Unicode character ranges
                    // Does not replace combined characters (\ufb20-\ufb4f)
                    // See
                    // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_and_HTML_for_the_Hebrew_alphabet
                    s = s. replaceAll("[\u05b0-\u05c7]", "");
                }
                if (!showMeteg) {
                    // Remove meteg based on Unicode character ranges
                    // Does not replace combined characters (\ufb20-\ufb4f)
                    // See
                    // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_and_HTML_for_the_Hebrew_alphabet
                    s = s.replaceAll("\u05bd", "");
                }
                ssb.append(s);
                ssb.append("\n");
                offset += s.length() + 1;
            }
        }

        sectionNames = sectionNamesList.toArray(new String[0]);

        currentFilename = filename;

        Log.v(TAG, "ssb.length()=" + ssb.length() +
                 ", daavenText.getText().length()=" +
                daavenText.getText().length() +
                ", showNikud=" + showNikud +
                ", showMeteg=" + showMeteg +
                ", showSectionNames=" + showSectionNames +
                ", currentFilename=" + currentFilename
                );
```

After looking over the interface, I plan to replace the showNikud and showMeteg cases with [InputFilter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputFilter.html)s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this a known issue with a SpannableStringBuffer?

I see nothing in the source code to suggest a hard limit on the size of a `SpannableStringBuffer`. Given your experiences, my guess is that this is a problem particular to that device, due to a stupid decision by an engineer at the device manufacturer.

> Any suggested workarounds?

If you are distributing through the Google Play Store, block this device in your console.

Or, don't use one massive `TextView`, but instead use several smaller `TextView` widgets in a `ListView` (so they can be recycled), perhaps one per paragraph. This should have the added benefit of reducing your memory footprint.

Or, generate HTML and display the content in a `WebView`.

Comment: If I just create a ton of `TextView`s in a `ListView` (in a `ScrollView`), will `TextView`s that have scrolled off the screen be automatically recyled?

`WebView`s are unfortunately not an option, but I display vocalized Hebrew text and Android displays that backwards (the bug is fixed but only in ICS).

Comment: @shmuelp: "be automatically recyled?" -- with a well-written `Adapter`, yes.

Answer (score 0):

After writing (and having the user run) a test app, it appears that his device has this arbitrary limit for `SpannableStringBuilder`, but not `StringBuilder` or `StringBuffer`.  I tested a quick change to read into a `StringBuilder` and then create a `SpannableString` from the result.  Unfortunately, that means that I can't create the spans until it is fully read in.

I have to consider using multiple `TextView` objects in a `ListView`, as well as using `Html.FromHtml` to see if that works better for my app's long term plans.